# Button in GridView: How do I know which Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding

I want to have a button in each row of a GridView to perform actions on this row. I'm able to get the click, but how do I determine which row this button belongs to?

What I have at the moment is this:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Calibrations}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Voltage [kV]" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Voltage}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Filter" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilterName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Calibration Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CalibrationDate}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Calibration" Width="60">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Start" Click="OnStart" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>


        private void OnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // how do I know, on which item this button is
    }
```

Is there maybe some way to bind the item on this row to the RoutedEventArgs?

Comment: What about checking the Grid selected item property?

Comment: Don't know WPF but asp.net has an OnCommand event that you can specify CommandName and CommandType arguments that get passed into the eventargs of the handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the clicked `Button` will be the item you are looking for

Assuming your source class is `Calibration`

```
private void OnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Calibration clickedCalibration = button.DataContext as Calibration;
    // ...
}
```

Another way is to use a `Command` instead of the Click event. This would allow you to bind `CommandParameter` like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Examples of this can be found all over the net, here is one: [Pass Command Parameter to RelayCommand](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/SilverlightWPFandXAML/76e6b583-edb1-4e23-95f6-7ad8510c0f88/pass-command-parameter-to-relaycommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about using an OnSelectedIndexChanged changed event on your GridView?

```
public void Grid_selectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = Grid.SelectedRow;
}
```